# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'hstack'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am following [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.hstack.html) doc for `hstack`.

```
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
b = torch.tensor([4, 5, 6])
torch.hstack((a,b))
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'hstack'
```

Here is the torch version that results in this error:

```
torch.__version__
'1.6.0+cpu'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can't tell from just this. Show your code and the *full* error message, including complete stack trace. Did you name a file `torch.py`?

Comment: The question and its answer are both reasonable; I don't see why this should stay closed!

Comment: Thanks, I also added a vote to reopen.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently you are calling a function that does not exist YET in your PyTorch version --this is what the error message is about.

Your link points to the help page related to developers preview: note `.8.0a0+342069f` version number in the top left corner. When clicking, Click here to view docs for latest stable release. link - an error message come.

This function becomes available in torch version `1.8.0.` --until then consider using `torch.cat` with `dim=1'.

```
torch.cat([a,b], dim=1)  # a, b - 2d torch.Tensors
```

Comment: [`torch.hstack` is a function that's supposed to exist.](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.hstack.html)

Comment: to @user2357112-supports-monica, @parth-tamane: SOLVED: apparently your link points to the help page related to developers preview: note ".8.0a0+342069f" version number in the top left corner. When clicking `Click here to view docs for latest stable release.` link - an error message appears. So this function becomes available in 1.8.0. until then - consider using `torch.cat`

Comment: That would explain it. It looks like `torch.hstack` actually becomes available in 1.7.0, not 1.8.0, though.